# Does Big Hat Logan restock?

Tags: dark-souls

After Big Hat Logan dissappears after I place Lordvessel on Firelink Altar does he have in his store spells I've already bought? Is it possible to get the same spell twice from him during single playthrough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Big Hat Logan will only sell you one copy of each spell per play through.

However, if you want multiple copies of 'soul spear' or 'homing soul mass', you can buy them from Griggs of Vinheim in the firelink shrine after Big Hat Logan leaves for Dukes Archive.

Comment: Are you sure? I vaguely remember being able to re-buy Soul spear from him after he moved to the Archives.